# Stack Overflow went read-only two times today and no details at any resource

Tags: support

Today, Stack Overflow went read-only in the morning (IST) and came back after some time.

[image]

Now again it went read-only.

[image]

> This pertains only to a specific site but the announcements were made on [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) and on [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/) and it is common for the entire network.

Both of them are updated on 21<sup>st</sup> July and no new information after that. So, the question is:

#### If the maintenance is for only a specific site, won't it be updated on the above two resources?

Comment: Cross site duplication [Why is Stack Overflow in read-only mode?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353718/2451726)

Comment: @Arulkumar no my question is the bolded text at the bottom(_won't the information be added to resources_) + that post is made for the morning read-only

Comment: Something not good is going on somewhere in SE, maybe hosting, maybe database.... MSE now suffer from occasional 404 errors as well. Hopefully, they will fix it soon.

Comment: only happens to SO. not even MSO.(made me think that they are separating SO from other SE sites)

Comment: This was not scheduled - people are looking into the causes.

Comment: "made me think that they are separating SO from other SE sites", that has been the case for a long time already.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is not planned.

There's an issue with connection pool timeouts I'm investigating. Normally, we disable said spill and opt for a few error pages when it happens over a read-only self-recovery, but due to the dynamics of the data center failover we had this re-enabled. It's just been disabled in a prod build that just went out and I'll be digging into the connection pool issues now.

There are a lot of contributing factors that can funnel into this result. It's ultimately the result of us being efficient here. While that's often a good thing (fewer servers to maintain, buy, etc.), it's not so good for per-server bottlenecks like connection pools. We can push those to the limits fairly routinely. Today, we're pushing way past those limits and I'm currently digging into why.

Comment: Any updates? Post mortem?

Comment: Any updates on this?